# combine data of multiple rows from multiple tables in single row and show multiple rows of data based on input

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem regarding making a data table that incorporates data of two other data tables, depending on what the input is in the input sheet.

These are my sheets:

1. sheet 1) [Data table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5QAT.png)
2. sheet 2) [Data table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otEUK.png)
3. sheet 3) Input sheet:
   In this sheet  one fills in the origin, destination, and month.
4. sheet 4) Output sheet:

   - Row(s) with characteristics that are a combination of the data in data table 1 and data table 2: 1 column for each characteristic in the row:
     (General; Month; Origin; feature 1; feature 2; month max; month min; Transit point; feature 1; feature 2; feature 3; month max; month min; Destination; feature 1; feature 2; month max; month min;) => feature 3 of origin and destination don't have to be incorporated in the output!

Depending on the month, origin and destination filled in in the input sheet; the output has to list all the possible rows (routes) with that origin and that destination and the temperatures in that month at the origin, transit point and destination.

I have tried `VLOOKUP(MATCH)`, but that only helps for 1 row. not if I want to list all possible rows..

I don't think this problem is that difficult, but I am really a rookie in Excel. Maybe it could work with a simple macro..

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear about some of your question, but perhaps you could adapt this solution to work for you?

http://thinketg.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

ColA ColB
a   1
b   2
c   3
a   4
b   5
c   6
a   7
b   8
    9
    10
    11
    7
    8
    9
    9
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20

In Cell E1, enter c (this is the value you are looking up).
In Cell F1, enter the function below and hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

=IF(ROWS(B$1:B1)<=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$20,$E$1),INDEX($B$1:$B$20,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$20=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$20)-ROW($E$1)+1),ROWS(B$1:B1))),"")